# Vb.Net Message box with input validation

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, messagebox, logic-error

So i'm getting a new laptop and to help me decide I came up with a points system. I have made an application to help with calculation and it consists of a series to check boxes with different options for different categories of components etc (CPU, RAM etc). They're given points based on how good they are.
I have a few lines of code that checks to see if more than one component per category has been selected.
If more than 1 has then a message box pops up telling the user then resetting the options.
However, the message box comes up twice after the first go.

Error video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDgR4.jpg

This is my first vb.net solo GUI program so be kind.

Many thanks,
:)

[image: This is the program UI]

```
Public Class Form1
Dim IS_R54500 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_R53500 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_R34300 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_Gb4 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_Gb8 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_Screen14 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_Screen15 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_SSD128 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_SSD256 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_SSD512 As Boolean = False
Dim IS_USBA As Integer = 0
Dim IS_USBC As Integer = 0
Dim IS_HDMI As Integer = 0
Dim IS_DP As Integer = 0
Dim Total As Integer = 0

Public Sub R54500_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles R54500.CheckedChanged
    IS_R54500 = True
End Sub

Public Sub R53500_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles R53500.CheckedChanged
    IS_R53500 = True
End Sub

Public Sub R34300_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles R34300.CheckedChanged
    IS_R34300 = True
End Sub

Public Sub Gb4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Gb4.CheckedChanged
    IS_Gb4 = True
End Sub

Public Sub Gb8_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Gb8.CheckedChanged
    IS_Gb8 = True
End Sub

Public Sub Screen14_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Screen14.CheckedChanged
    IS_Screen14 = True
End Sub

Public Sub Screen15_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Screen15.CheckedChanged
    IS_Screen15 = True
End Sub

Public Sub SSD128_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SSD128.CheckedChanged
    IS_SSD128 = True
End Sub

Public Sub SSD256_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SSD256.CheckedChanged
    IS_SSD256 = True
End Sub

Public Sub SSD512_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SSD512.CheckedChanged
    IS_SSD512 = True
End Sub

Public Sub USBA_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles USBA.TextChanged
    IS_USBA = USBA.Text()
End Sub

Public Sub USBC_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles USBC.TextChanged
    IS_USBC = USBC.Text()
End Sub

Public Sub HDMI_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HDMI.TextChanged
    IS_HDMI = HDMI.Text()
End Sub

Public Sub DP_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DP.TextChanged
    IS_DP = DP.Text()
End Sub

Public Sub Results_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Results.Click
    Results.Text = CStr(Total)
End Sub

Public Sub Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click
    Total = 0

    If IS_R54500 And IS_R53500 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_R54500 = False
        IS_R53500 = False
        R54500.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        R53500.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If IS_R54500 And IS_R34300 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_R54500 = False
        IS_R34300 = False
        R54500.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        R34300.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If IS_R53500 And IS_R34300 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_R53500 = False
        IS_R34300 = False
        R53500.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        R34300.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If IS_Gb8 And IS_Gb4 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_Gb4 = False
        IS_Gb8 = False
        Gb4.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Gb8.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If IS_Screen14 And IS_Screen15 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_Screen14 = False
        IS_Screen15 = False
        Screen14.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Screen15.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If IS_SSD128 And IS_SSD256 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_SSD128 = False
        IS_SSD256 = False
        SSD128.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        SSD256.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If IS_SSD128 And IS_SSD512 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_SSD128 = False
        IS_SSD512 = False
        SSD128.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        SSD512.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
    If IS_SSD512 And IS_SSD256 = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")
        IS_SSD512 = False
        IS_SSD256 = False
        SSD512.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        SSD256.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If

    If IS_R54500 = True Then
        Total += 3
    End If
    If IS_R53500 = True Then
        Total += 2
    End If
    If IS_R34300 = True Then
        Total += 1
    End If
    If IS_Gb8 = True Then
        Total += 2
    End If
    If IS_Gb4 = True Then
        Total += 1
    End If
    If IS_Screen14 = True Then
        Total += 1
    End If
    If IS_Screen15 = True Then
        Total += 2
    End If
    If IS_SSD128 = True Then
        Total += 1
    End If
    If IS_SSD256 = True Then
        Total += 2
    End If
    If IS_SSD512 = True Then
        Total += 3
    End If
    Total += CInt(IS_USBA)
    Total += CInt(IS_USBC)
    Total += CInt(IS_HDMI)
    Total += CInt(IS_DP)

    ''MessageBox.Show("There is more than one option chosen in a certain category." & vbCrLf & "Please fix this error and then try again.", "Error")

    Results.Text = Total
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images (or videos). Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @Steve This is very wordy. Would you mind explaining what you would like? Would you like me to add a copy of my code?

Comment: Well the easiest solution would be to simply use a radio group rather than check boxes.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict for this projects and all vb.net projects. You are trying to assign the .Text property which is a String to an Integer variable. Also .Text is a property not a method. Following .Text with parenthesis indicates a method is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the proper controls, you can save yourself a lot of code. `RadioButton`s only allow a single selection in a container. A container can be a group box or a form.

Using a `NumericUpDown` will insure you get a number for the Ports area. A user can put anything in a `TextBox`.

I used the `GetSelectedRadioButton` several times in the button code. This function takes a container holding radio buttons and returns the selected radio button. It does this with a bit of Linq magic where it checks each radio button in the container until it finds one where `.Checked = True`. This radio button is assigned to `rb` and returned to the calling code. If it doesn't find a checked radio button it returns `Nothing`.

If we tried to check the `.Name` property of the radio button when it is `Nothing` we would get the dreaded NRE (Null Reference Exception) So, the first thing we do is check if the returned radio button `Is Nothing`. If the user has failed to make a selection, we show a message box and exit the sub.

If the user has made a selection we use a `Select Case` or an `If` statement to increment `Total`.

When it comes to the ports we loop through the controls getting the `Value` property (a `Decimal`). To add it to Total, it must first be converted to an `Integer`.

Finally display the Total.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim Total As Integer
    Dim rb = GetSelectedRadioButton(gbProcessor)
    If rb Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a Processor.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Select Case GetSelectedRadioButton(gbProcessor).Name
            Case "rb545"
                Total += 3
            Case "rb535"
                Total += 2
            Case "rb343"
                Total += 1
        End Select
    End If
    Dim rb1 = GetSelectedRadioButton(gbMemory)
    If rb1 Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select Memory")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If rb1.Name = "rb4" Then
            Total += 1
        Else
            Total += 2
        End If
    End If
    Dim rb2 = GetSelectedRadioButton(gbScreenSize)
    If rb2 Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a Screen Size.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If rb2.Name = "rb14" Then
            Total += 1
        Else
            Total += 2
        End If
    End If
    Dim rb3 = GetSelectedRadioButton(gbStorage)
    If rb3 Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select Storage size.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Select Case rb3.Name
            Case "rb128"
                Total += 1
            Case "rb256"
                Total += 2
            Case "rb512"
                Total += 3
        End Select
    End If
    For Each ctrl As NumericUpDown In gbPorts.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)
        Total += CInt(ctrl.Value)
    Next
    lblCalculate.Text = Total.ToString
End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedRadioButton(Container As Control) As RadioButton
    Dim rb = Container.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Return rb
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Public Sub SSD512_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SSD512.CheckedChanged
    IS_SSD512 = True
End Sub
```

with

```
Public Sub SSD512_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SSD512.CheckedChanged
    IS_SSD512 = SSD512.Checked
End Sub
```

I think the thing is that when the form loads, it calls to uncheck the boxes, so your variables become TRUE.